# Gradle не собирает проект. Maven

Tags: android-studio, maven, gradle

[image: Gradle не собирает проект. Maven.]

Добавил в `allprojects/repositries` `maven` в `build`(в проект).

Добавил строчку `compile 'com.github.User:Repo:Tag'` в модуль.

Ошибка:

> Error:Failed to resolve: Could not resolve com.github.User:Repo:Tag.
>   Required by:
>       project :myapplication

Comment: Автор, откуда вы взяли, что ДОЛЖНО собираться? Это и не может собираться в принципе.

Comment: После того, как вы опубликовали с помощью jitpack свою либу, надо зайти на страницу, ввести в поле свой репозиторий, нажать Look up и ниже будет корректная инструкция для подключения. в FAQ указан общий формат